# Impact of file socket descriptor closed twice bug in multithreaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, fopen, file-descriptor, file-read

```
fd = open("file", O_RDONLY);
if (fd < 0) exit(1);

while((res = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)))){
if (res < 0){
close(fd);
fprintf(stderr, "Read error!\n");
break;
} else {
printf("Read %zd bytes\n", res);
}
}
close (fd);
```

In the single-threaded program this is an obvious bug: 'fd' is being closed twice. What could be the impact of this bug in a multithreaded program?